# In Android external allocation too large for this process error for images

Tags: android, memory, heap-memory, dalvik

Please give some solutions of this problem "external allocation too large for this process." when i navigate from one activity to others. Although if i make second activity as main activity, it works fine but when i navigate it from others activities it crushes.

In that activity, i am using many heavy images with scroll horizontally. I have seen many links but still no solutions
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to use many large images together as that would evidently get the app to run Out of Memory. Instead you should try resizing the images. Also you should try gallery view if you want a horizontal list of images. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966) for re-sizing the image

Comment: Thanks Freiza.Now i have find solution.It was due to put large images in drawable-MDP folder instead of drawable-HDP. Because it takes large memory on drawable-mdp